# 'xdg-open' does not open the default browser

Tags: default-browser

I have the following scenario:

[Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) machine with Firefox and Google Chrome installed, Chrome being my default browser.

I check these actions in the shell:

```
cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
cat /etc/mailcap
cat /.config/mimeapps.list
cat /.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache

x-www-browser-> chrome is launch
xdg-mime query default text/html
response:
google-chrome.desktop
```

And it does not appear Firefox by any side, always Chrome. This is fine. Also check:

Click on a desktop file *file.html* → Chrome is launched.

And now comes the strange behaviour. Say I run:

```
xdg-open "http://www.example.com"
```

For some strange reason, it always opens Firefox. What should I do?

Comment: What is meant by *"it does not appear Firefox by any side"*? A [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate) masterpiece?

Answer (score 52):

To set a default browser, make sure that a `.desktop` file exists for your preferred browser. I'll be setting Mozilla Iceweasel for this example:

```
ls /usr/share/applications/iceweasel.desktop
```

Output:

```
iceweasel.desktop
```

Assured you have the file, run:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser iceweasel.desktop

# Test that it works
xdg-open "http://example.com"
```

#### If you don't have a *.desktop* file:

I use the program `surf`, which doesn't have a .desktop file. To set this as your web browser, first create the file *~/.local/share/applications/surf.desktop* with this following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=surf
Comment=Surf minimal web browser
Terminal=false
Exec=surf
Categories=Network;WebBrowser
```

While not all of this content is required, it helps categorize the file for any future use.

Set the default browser like normal:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser surf.desktop
```

And now you're good to go!

Comment: For me "xdg-settings get default-web-browser"       
returned "firefox.desktop" already.
But running
"xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop"
fixed my problem anyway.

Comment: I faced with same problem after adding Postman **.desktop** file following [their doc](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching_postman/installation_and_updates/#linux-installation)

`xdg-settings get default-web-browser` returned proper value.

Running @user2707671 advice to try to setup proper browser again fixed the problem

Comment: I use Luuntu and still cannot fix this. `xdg-open` always open Firefox.

Comment: on kde, if set fails, try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/62182/how-do-i-change-the-default-browser-that-konsole-opens-urls-with#comment1584875_216342

Comment: Also if you're on Ubuntu and your browser is packaged using a Snap, your application's desktop is _not_ named like `firefox.desktop` (as you see under `/snap/`), it's like `firefox_firefox.desktop` or `chromium_chromium.desktop`, as found under `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`

Answer (score 10):

*text/html* is for HTML files, i.e., if you open an HTML file then it would open in Google Chrome. For opening URLs, you need to have the `x-scheme-handler/https` and `x-scheme-handler/http` entries.

You can set that either with *xdg-mime*. For example, to set Google Chrome as the default browser for *xdg-open*:

```
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/https
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
```

Or you can add the following lines in file *~/.config/mimeapps.list*:

```
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
```

The above commands basically insert these lines into that file.

Note: you should obviously have the *google-chrome.desktop* file under *~/.local/share/applications* or the system-wide alternative location - */usr/share/applications*.

For changing the default browser overall, you also have to use *xdg-settings* as [shown by Nolan Akash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50893809/7787654).
*xdg-settings* changes the value of $BROWSER, so another way to change it is to explicitly assign the program (not the *.desktop file*) to the $BROWSER environment variable and export it.

```
export BROWSER=google-chrome
```

You usually would want to keep this like in [~/.bashrc file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) (or [the equivalent](https://wiki.debian.org/Zsh#Configuration) for the shell you use) or in the [~/.profile file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Operating_system_issues_in_Bash_startup) and log out and log in to have the environment updated and available for other programs to see.

Answer (score -7):

Just open the Chrome browser and set as the default browser.

Comment: For some reason this never works for me. The above answer does work.