# How do I set the default browser for xdg-open on Centos 7 if xdg-settings has no desktop environment

Tags: centos, centos7, xdgutils, default-browser

There are many questions similar to mine (e.g. [xdg-open not open default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172692/xdg-open-not-open-default-browser) or [xdgutils - xdg-settings not setting default-web-browser in gentoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209774/xdg-settings-not-setting-default-web-browser-in-gentoo), but none of the answers helped in my case. Therefor I ask for my particular situation:

---

On Centos 7 I have no free desktop manager running, I just run some X11 applications (like VS Code) from the command line where the DISPLAY variable is set to the X server on the (Windows) machine I connect from.

On the Centos machine I have two browsers installed, `firefox` and `google-chrome`. I can start both browsers just by typing `firefox` resp. `google-chrome` in the bash terminal.

`xdg-open` is available and it opens links in `google-chrome` - as does VS Code. However I want to change this to `firefox`.

I tried:

1. Ticking "Default browser" in Firefox's GUI preferences.
2. Using `xdg-settings`, but

   ```
   xdg-settings get default-web-browser
   ```

   returns "xdg-settings: unknown desktop environment"
3. Setting $BROWSER. In bash I issued

   ```
   export BROWSER=firefox
   ```

   but still `google-chrome` is started by `xdg-open`

**How can I set in this environment the default browser to firefox?**

---

Note: Strangely on another machine with Centos **6** (and "no desktop environment" either) the `export BROWSER` method works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The desired behavior can be set in the `mimeapps.list` configuration files described in the [XDG MIME Applications specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-latest.html).

**TLDR:**
In order to configure firefox as the default browser for your user create `~/.config/mimeapps.list` containing the following lines:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/ftp=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/chrome=firefox.desktop
text/html=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-htm=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-html=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-shtml=firefox.desktop
application/xhtml+xml=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-xhtml=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-xht=firefox.desktop
```

**Details:**
[`xdg-utils`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/) like [`xdg-open(1)`](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-open.html) and [`xdg-mime(1)`](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-mime.html) look for this file in the locations listed under the [File name and location](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-latest.html#file) section of this specification:

- `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/$desktop-mimeapps.list` user overrides, desktop-specific (for advanced users)
- `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list` user overrides (recommended location for user configuration GUIs)
- `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/$desktop-mimeapps.list` sysadmin and ISV overrides, desktop-specific
- `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/mimeapps.list` sysadmin and ISV overrides
- `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/$desktop-mimeapps.list` for completeness, deprecated, desktop-specific
- `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/mimeapps.list` for compatibility, deprecated
- `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/$desktop-mimeapps.list` distribution-provided defaults, desktop-specific
- `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/mimeapps.list` distribution-provided defaults

The locations for the `$XDG` variables are governed by the [XDG Base Directory specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). If you want to figure out where [`xdg-utils`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/) are looking for configuration in your particular case, run them with the `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL` environment variable like so:

```
$ XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=10 xdg-open 'https://www.example.com'
...
Checking /home/USERNAME/.config/mimeapps.list
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. The tip with `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL` was worth gold: In my case `~/.config/mimeapps.list` didn't do the job, but with the debugging variable I found out that the system looks for `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`, so i set the default entries there.